Null Fields Added After Upgrading to Java 17 and SAP JCo 3.1.6 in Spring Boot ETL Process
I have an ETL process that extracts data from SAP software and stores it in another database. Recently, I upgraded the project from Java 11 to Java 17 (Spring Boot) and updated the SAP JCo library from version 3.0.19 to 3.1.6.
After these upgrades, I noticed that null fields are being added to the database. For example, if a property like ID: (where ID has an empty value) exists, it is now stored in the database as ID with an empty string.
This behavior didn't occur before, so I believe it might be related to the recent changes. While I can address this in my code, I wanted to check if there is a configuration or property that could resolve this issue.
Does anyone know of a configuration or setting in SAP JCo or Spring Boot that could prevent null fields from being added to the database? Or maybe it's a feature?
Thank you!
I tried reviewing the code to see if there were any changes that could have caused null fields to be inserted into the database. Specifically, I checked if there were any modifications in how empty or null values are handled during the ETL process. I also looked into the SAP JCo and Spring Boot documentation to see if there were any new default behaviors introduced in the updated versions.
I expected that the behavior would remain the same as before the upgrade, where null or empty fields would not be added to the database. However, after the upgrade, I noticed that fields with empty values are now being inserted as empty strings in the database.

JCo does not know any database. So first you need to clarify: which component here is making inserts/updates in "the database"? What is "the database"? Do you mean the database underneath the SAP system? In that case there is probably an ABAP function module whose ABAP code makes DB updates. If so, which FM are you using? Or are you talking about a database that's used on the client side (Java side)? Then  there must be a JDBC driver being used somewhere. Perhaps the JDBC driver has a problem with Java 17, and you need to upgrade it as well? -- Lot's of missing details to attempt any answer...
